# How is "value type" variable freed from the stack when leaving method scope if it is still in use by another thread (passed by "ref")?

Tags: c#, .net-core, memory-management

Say we have a `method A` that declares variable 'int Q', starts another `method B` that accepts variable `Q` as `ref int` parameter in a new thread and returns.

Considering that, according to this answer, .NET passes "the address of variable Q in stack" to the `method B` when passed by reference - when control leaves the scope of `method A`, shouldn't the runtime clear the stack of variables allocates inside this method? Does this mean that if original thread continues to run (and allocating other variables on stack), `method B` may corrupt one of these variables because the "address" it refers to does not belong to variable `Q` anymore?

I'm definitely understanding this wrong as when I run the below snippet I don't notice any changes in `manyInts` array.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Outer();
    int[] manyInts = new int[100000];
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
private static void Outer()
{
    int crossThreadInt = 10;
    try
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() => AsyncInfiniteMethod(ref crossThreadInt));
        t.Wait(2000);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // ignored
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine(crossThreadInt);
    }
}
private static void AsyncInfiniteMethod(ref int number)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        number++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [what your code compiles to](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACh8AGAAn2IDoAVAC1gEMMBLAOwHMA3BWp1iAViHlhAZjqEaAYQoBvCjXU0ADlC4A3dgBcYopHRQ0A8gFcjUABQBKNRtXkN7mrwM0wUCAGd/Vg4MAEkebwBeGipJDw18JAYAJSseO0caSIA+GgBBfwBPHjBwgDNeLiMAWRgDFggMO1gynz9A4JhOcIMHBziNAF9ndW09Q2N6U3xzAuLSngqeKpha+sbmmFavGh4rAFtgGCgnNxcRmmHyQaA===). See how the stuff captured by the lambda -- `crossThreadInt` -- is lifed into a field on `<>c__DisplayClass0_0`. That's where it lives, and `<>c__DisplayClass0_0` lives for as long as `AsyncInfiniteMethod` is executing

Comment: note: `int[] manyInts = new int[100000];` doesn't use the stack much (just some ref popping); that is a heap allocation, so it wouldn't really have any overlap *anyway*

Comment: sounds so evident (especially the myInts part). Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you "capture" a variable into a lambda delegate or ananoymous method: it changes location - it is no longer a stack variable. Essentially, this:

```cs
int crossThreadInt = 10;
// ...
var t = Task.Run(() => AsyncInfiniteMethod(ref crossThreadInt));
```

becomes:

```cs
var captureContext = new SomeCompilerGeneratedClass();
captureContext.crossThreadInt = 10;
// ...
var t = Task.Run(captureContext.SomeCompilerGeneratedMethod);

class SomeCompilerGeneratedClass {
    public int crossThreadInt;
    public void SomeCompilerGeneratedMethod() {
        AsyncInfiniteMethod(ref this.crossThreadInt)
    }
    // etc
}
```

So: the issue doesn't exist: the integer was never a stack local variable; it is a field on a class. The capture-context object (that owns the lifetime) is kept alive because it is the "target" instance of the delegate.

Comment: thank you @MarcGravell. Will this still be non-problematic if `AsyncInfiniteMethod` would make a long-running P/Invoke call behind the scenes passing this int on?
Wondering if it is possible for unmanaged code to misuse this memory in some circumstances. E.g. maybe GC can move this int to a different place in memory leaving the unmanaged code's reference stale? How would .NET behave in this case, will it fail with some kind of memory error?

Comment: @Egor in that case, the `ref int` is still tracked and updated by the GC, if the object is moved; it is cateogrized as something called an "interior (managed) pointer", and it works just fine. The fundamental architecture of .NET depends on interior pointers working correctly with regards to GC. There is no problem here, basically. Interior pointers also apply to array contents, as well as fields on classes